# How to generates an ECDSA signature over the P256 elliptic curve with a given privatekey in iOS

Tags: swift, signature, ecdsa

I have integrated Swift Crypto, the example shows how to generate a new private key\public key, then sign.

```
    let signingKey = try P256.Signing.PrivateKey()
    let signature = try signingKey.signature(for: hash)
```

but I want to use a given privatekey, just like the code in nodejs

```
  import { ecsign} from 'ethereumjs-util';
  const { r, s, v } = ecsign(hash, Buffer.from(givenPivatekey, 'hex'));
  const signature = Buffer.concat([ r, s ]);
```

so what's the solution

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Well. Let me end the the question by my own.
link the libsecp256k1.a in my project
use secp256k1_ecdsa_recoverable_signature

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).